# What are the consequences of not reaching target workers in a dataflow job?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

[image]

My apache beam scio dataflow job is asking for more workers than my current quota. The job completes successfully, but is limited to 575 workers. What are the consequences of not giving it the RAM it is asking for. More disk IO of intermediate steps? Slower sink IO? Does it depend on what's going on with the job? In particular, my job is pretty simple really has 2 steps:

```
-aggregateByKey 
-DO IO per key
```

I can run my own experiments, but I'm also interested in the cost of the job, since it isn't extremely time sensitive operation (aka I'm okay letting it run longer if it is cheaper)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, your job will have a higher runtime than if your quota was higher, but the aggregate amount of time spent performing work by all workers should be about the same.

Dataflow bills you on the amount of time each CPU, memory and storage unit is allocated. If the total CPU-hours, RAM GB-hours and storage GB-hours are about the same, your job should cost about the same.

Note: Dataflow also charges by the amount of bytes shuffled if you use the shuffle service. This should also not be affected by the number of workers.